# Multiple user sessions with SPA using MSAL

Tags: single-page-application, adal, azure-ad-msal, adal.js, msal.js

I have had a scenario come across a few times now where I require Password Grant flow in my SPA apps.

For example, one user is logged into my single-page-application (SPA) using MSALjs.  All API’s they call to my services will be under that user context.  There is a part in the app that requires the user to hand the device to another person to authorize some specific functionality (like an override or signature). Once that operation is completed everything continues under the original user context.

It would be great if MSAL could handle multiple sessions for that use case.  Today we handle that by creating an API that takes in the other users credentials and use Password Grant Flow behind the scenes.

Is anyone aware of any client-side functionality in MSALjs that allows the SPA to have multiple user sessions at the same time?  This way I can route the second user through Implicit Flow as well while maintaining the original session.  Once the second user is finished I can log them out and keep the first session going.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the new version of MSAL.js package for this, it's called @azure/msal-browser.
It uses Authorization Code Flow with PKCE and it can handle many accounts in an SPA.
Sample code:

```
import * as msal from "@azure/msal-browser";

// 1. Intitialize the auth client - this only needs to run once
const authClient = new msal.PublicClientApplication({
    auth: {
        clientId: "yourClientId",
        authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/yourTenantId",
        redirectUri: "yourRedirectUrl",
    },
    cache: {
        cacheLocation: "localStorage", // This configures where your cache will be stored
        storeAuthStateInCookie: false, // Set this to "true" if you are having issues on IE11 or Edge
    }
});

// 2. Log a new user in and return their account object - call for each person you want to log in
const getLoggedInUser = () => {
    return authClient.handleRedirectPromise().then((redirectResponse) => {
        // If this is the return redirect of the login flow
        if (redirectResponse && redirectResponse.account) {
            return account;
        }
        
        // This is not the return redirect - trigger the flow
        authClient.loginRedirect();
    });
}

// 3. (Optional) Get account objects for all logged in users
const getAllLoggedInUsers = () => {
    return authClient.getAllAccounts();
}

// 4. Get an access token for a particular account, you probably need to expose scopes as a parameter too
const getAccessToken = (user) => {
    const request = {
        scopes: ["yourScopeUri1", "yourScopeUri2"],
        forceRefresh: true, // Set this to "true" to ignore token cache
        account = user;
    };    
    
    return authClient.acquireTokenSilent(request)
        .then(tokenResponse => tokenResponse.accessToken)
        .catch(error => {
            if (error instanceof msal.InteractionRequiredAuthError) {
                console.warn("Silent token acquisition failed. Acquiring token using popup.");
                return authClient.acquireTokenPopup(request)
                    .then(tokenResponse => tokenResponse.accessToken)
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.error(error);
                    });
            } else {
                console.error(error);
            }
    });
}
```

Documentation:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-browser
- https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-browser#msal-basics